# I can't set a string in a TextView in an Android app (using Java)

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I'm building a simple calculator Android app in Java that will receive 2 numbers as inputs and when the user presses one of the 4 action buttons (+, -, *, /) the exercise and it's solution will appear in the bottom of the screen inside a TextView in this format:

{num1} {action} {num2} = {solution}

I tried to declare a string and form the exercise's string in it and in the end I used "setText" to change the TextView but instead of showing the full exercise when I run the app it shows something like "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCom".

Here is an example for the string I form when the user clicks on the + button:

exerciseStr = etNum1.toString() + " + " + etNum2.toString() + " = " + String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(etNum1.getText().toString())+Integer.valueOf(etNum2.getText() + ""));

Does anybody know what the issue may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `getText()` befor calling `toString()`:

```
exerciseStr = etNum1.getText().toString() + " + " + etNum2.getText().toString() + " = " + String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(etNum1.getText().toString())+Integer.valueOf(etNum2.getText() + ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to like this.

```
exerciseStr = etNum1.getText().toString() + " + " + etNum2.getText().toString() + " = "  + String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(etNum1.getText().toString())+Integer.valueOf(etNum2.getText() + ""));
```